# (C#) Selenium - How to validate if a tr exists in an HTML page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

> I need to check in an HTML page if the "tr" exists, if the td does not exist that it condonue to execute the code and does not present an error for not having found, as it presents in the following image.

[image]

> It is because in some pages there is [tr: nth-of-type (3)] and in other pages it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - please use code, do not put screenshots here :)

Easiest (but not fastest) way of solving this is:

```
try 
{
    IWebElement nomeDoPortal2 = secondRow...
    // do something if exist
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    // do something if it doesn't exist
}
```